# Why by decreasing the depth of the random forest, the overall accuracy decreases?

Tags: random-forest

If you decrease the maximum depth that the random forest can reach instead of letting the RF to fully grow, what happens to the performance and Overall Accuracy (OA) of the RF? As I have tested the OA decreases. What is the reason?

Comment: Maybe it is obvious but... what does OA stand for ?

Comment: Overall Accuracy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tree depth determines how flexible the model is. A deeper tree can fit more complicated functions. Therefore, increasing tree depth should increase performance on the training set. But, increased flexibility also gives greater ability to overfit the data, and generalization performance may suffer if depth is increased too far (i.e. test set performance may decrease). Another way of saying this is that increasing depth decreases bias at the expense of increasing variance. Random forests can combat this increase in variance by averaging over multiple trees, but are not immune to overfitting. Getting the best generalization performance typically requires tuning the tree depth to achieve a proper balance between bias and variance  (e.g. by optimizing the out-of-bag error).

Comment: This answer makes sense to me but I have also read that random forests is resistant to overfitting and that trees should be grown fully.

Comment: I would recommend reading the article "Random Forests and Adaptive Nearest Neighbors" by Lin and Jeon (2006).  In Section 3 they discuss optimizing the terminal node size.  I don't think we need to optimize the tree depth (should probably be as large as possible), but may want to customize when to stop based on the number of observations in the node.

Comment: @PeterCalhoun Constraining leaf node size is related to constraining depth, because size constraints are implemented by stopping the splitting process (preventing a branch from growing deeper). This answer is intended to cover depth constraints in general, which may be implemented in various specific ways (including constraining both maximum tree depth and minimum leaf node size).

Comment: @Seanosapien Random forests are indeed resistant to overfitting, but are not immune as some people claim. What's true is that generalization performance does not decrease as new trees are added. So, random forests don't overfit as a function of forest size. But, they can overfit as a function of other hyperparameters.